# A bound on the top homology of a complement to a variety in $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $V$ be a subvariety of $\mathbb C^n$ with irreducible components of dimension >$0$. Is $H_{2n-1}(\mathbb C^n\setminus V)=0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly true, though I don't know the best way of proving it.

One way to see it is that if you take the one-point compactifications $V^+\subset(\mathbb{C}^n)^+=S^{2n}$, you get a connected space, since all components contain the point at infinity. The result then follows by Alexander duality in $S^{2n}$.

Answer (score 4):

The sharp bound is this: For any closed algebraic set $V$ of codimension $d$ in ${\Bbb C}^n$, with $U={\Bbb C}^n \setminus V$, one has $\pi_i(U) = 0$ for $0 < i\leq 2d-2$ and $\pi_{2d-1}(U) \neq 0$.  Using the Hurewicz isomorphism, you get the same vanishing and non-vanishing for homology.

A simple proof is in the appendix to my notes (with Fulton) on equivariant cohomology, http://www.math.washington.edu/~dandersn/eilenberg/ .  A slick reason for vanishing was pointed out by David Speyer: given a (nice) map of an $i$-sphere into $U$, the (real) lines between the points in image of the sphere and points in $V$ sweep out a space of dimension at most $(2n-2d)+i+1$.  When $i<2d-1$, you can pick a point in $U$ not lying on any such line, and contract your sphere down to that point.  The non-vanishing happens because all algebraic sets have nontrivial fundamental classes in Borel-Moore homology.  (Vanishing can also be proved using B-M homology.)

Comment: Oops -- now that my browser is processing math, I realized I completely misread the question.  Sorry, this doesn't answer it!  (Of course, you already have James Cranch's fine answer.)

Comment: Dave, nevertheless, thanks for writing this, I even understand what question you were answering :) ! 